# How can i call this javascript function inside swift code

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

This is javascript function from a webView

```
function draft(){
         var getAllHtmlCode = getHtml();
         Android.fullCode(getAllHtmlCode);
    }
```

now i want to call this fullcode function with parameter in my swift code
i was try this way

```
var c:String?

func fullcode(getAllHtmlCode) {

c = getAllHtmlCode

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript`.

```
let myJavaScript : String = "window.alert("Hello!");"
self.myWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: myJavaScript)
```

Comment: answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826083/how-can-i-call-javascript-function-in-ios-swift